# How to get the Lat & Long value of nearest 100 meters location to the current location

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I need to get the lat and long values of nearest 100 meters location in any direction to the current location, here is my code,

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCenter;
double ms = 100;
double scalingFactor = ABS( (cos(2 * M_PI * currentLocationCoordinates.latitude / 360.0) ));
if ([misson.location.latitude doubleValue] == 0.0 && [mission.location.longitude doubleValue] == 0.0) {
    annotationCenter.latitude = currentLocationCoordinates.latitude+(ms/103.5*1000);
    annotationCenter.longitude = currentLocationCoordinates.longitude+(ms/(scalingFactor * (103.5*1000)));
}
```

I don't know weather it is correct or not,Please help me out.

Comment: So you want the points for a circle with a radius of 100m around your current location? Why then are you checking if the latitude of myLocation and the longitude of mission are 0?  Do you mean you want a point that is 100m along a line from currentLocation towards mission?

Comment: Here I have my current location ,I need to find the lat & Long values that is 100 meters near to my current location towards any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at an article by Chris Veness:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Your problem seems to be calculating "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point". The example code is all JavaScript, but it is simple and short, and you should have no problem to port it to Objective-C.